# jquery based navigation for multiple pages in one page website

Tags: jquery, navigation, multipage

I'm working on creating a website that is effectively one page however it consists of multiple pages.

the html:

```
<p class="nav">
<a id="1" class="active" href="#">Home</a>
<a id="2" href="#">Our Designs</a>
<a id="3" href="#">Our Team</a>
<a id="4" href="#">Contact</a>
</p>
<div id="p1">
</div>
<div id="p2">
</div>
<div id="p3">
</div>
<div id="p4">
</div>
```

the css:

```
#p1,
#p2,
#p3,
#p4{
    display:none;
}
.pactive{
    display:block !important;
}
```

the jquery:

```
$("#1").click(function(){
  $(".active").toggleClass("active");
  $("#1").toggleClass("active");
  $(".pactive").fadeout(200);
  setTimeout(function(){
    $(".pactive").toggleClass("pactive");
  }, 200);
  setTimeout(function(){
    $("#p1").toggleClass("pactive");
  }, 200);
  setTimeout(function(){
    $(".pactive").fadein(200);
  }, 200);
});
```

there is one for each link

How do I get this to work?

Comment: The idea here is that p# represents a different page with p1 being the home page .pactive is used to make the page show when the link is clicked. Imagine a tabbed page like  [link](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) but as a whole website.

Comment: essentially how ever i dont want to click on it twice and nothing show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$(".nav").children("a").click(function(){
  $(".active").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
  $(".pactive").fadeOut(200,function(){
      $(this).removeClass("pactive");   
  });
  $("#p" + this.id).fadeIn(200,function(){
      $(this).addClass("pactive"); 
  });
});
```

I changed the `.toggleClass()` calls to either `.addClass()` or `.removeClass()` as applicable to make the code more readable...

Also, make sure to call `.fadeOut()` and `.fadeIn()` properly, as your code has `fadeout` and `fadein` (all lowercase)

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/nNBWX/)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$(".nav a").click(function(){
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    var id = this.id;
    $(".pactive").fadeOut(200).promise().done(function(){
        $(".pactive").toggleClass("pactive");
        $("#p"+id).toggleClass("pactive");
        $(".pactive").fadeIn(200);
    });
});
```

Also, remove the `display : block !important`.

In a this function, `this` represent the clicked element. Since you are using a number as an id (which is a bad practice by the way), you can easily target his paragraph by making a concatenation.

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/kucx5/1/

Comment: You are right, since i did not tested it, i couldn't see that the fadeOut callback wasn't called. A promise do the job though. Thank for your fiddle, i got it working!

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Interesting answer, I never thought of using `.promise()` + `.done()` but it seems useful for a lot of things...
+1

Comment: @darkajax Yes well, because i don't have a `.pactive` right after the loading, the fadeOut callback never happenned since `$('.pactive')` was empty. I hate using promise instead of calback, but i didn't want to change the DOM or the document ready script. But yeah promise is usefull when you want something to always happen :)